# О словах со старославянским корнем

Tags: словообразование

Почему данные слова расположены в одном гнезде, если они имеют совершенно разные значения:
**блажь** (ерунда, дурость) - **блаж**ить [вообще просторечное слово] (совершать блажь, то есть  дурить) - у**блаж**ить (удовлетворить требования).

Comment: ‟Ублажать” произошло от ‟блаженство”. ‟Блажь” и ‟блажить” – это архаизмы, и неизвестно, связаны ли они со словом ‟блаженство”.

Comment: У Тихонова для "блаженства" и "блаженный" есть отдельная статья. "Блажить", "блажь" и "ублажить" находятся в другой словарной статье, вот и интересно, почему он их так расположил, если значения не очень похожи.

Answer (score 2):

потому что блажь - это плотское удовольствие, а не ерунда, дурость. А ерундой и дуростью оно становится, потому что стремление к плотскому удовольствию - это грех, то есть, априори, неверное поведение, так как потакает земным страстям, то есть сметному в человеке.

[Блажь](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%8C) - неразумные желания, поэтому дурь. Бражить - придуриваться, кривляться, хотеть непонятно чего. Благой, блажной - помешанный. Если еще добавить, что излишняя веселость без причины (которая признак дурачины), это связь с психо-невротическими расстройствами, то блажной по-современному - это невротик, либо не знающий удовлетворения и спокойствия, либо слишком веселый для спокойного. Ублажить - удовлетворить чьё-то желание, причем зачастую сперва спровоцировав реакцию желания.

Блаженный - напротив, употребляется как тот, чьи желания удовлетворены верой в Бога или умственной дисфункцией. Поэтому это блаженство, отсутствие мирских(смертных) желаний и страстей, может уже иметь положительную коннотацию. Хотя блаженными называют как святых, так и сумасшедших.

Гедонизм, если вам такое слово знакомо. блажь - это pleased, pleasure. please - это не пожалуйста, просто его стали переводить как пожалуйста. [please](https://www.etymonline.com/word/please#etymonline_v_16475:%7E:text=to%20please%20or%20satisfy) - это сделайте приятное, причём себе - ублажите себя, удовлетворите своё желание, be pleased. А по[жал](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#:%7E:text=2.-,%D0%96%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC,-%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE)уйста - это проявите жалость ко мне. Так что если вы задумаетесь на секунду о смыслах слов, которые повторяете, вам сразу станет понятна причина культуры потребления, откуда ноги растут.

Или вы серьезно не понимаете смысл слова, а видите только семантические ассоциативные значения?

Стремление к телесному благу, к телесному и страстнОму удовлетворению - это блажь. Делать то, что "хочется" телу. Невозможность контроля своих страстей. **То что вы одно слово заменили другим, без фразеологизации, не дает ровным счетом ничего, никакого смысла в этой операции нет.**

Слово - это не набор букв, **слово - это когда вы можете этот набор букв раскрутить во фразу, содержащую не номинативное утверждение, потому что фраза это не номинативное утверждение, а предикативную связку или причину и следствие.** То есть слово, это название впечатление произошедшего по причине. **Если же причины нет, а просто предикат - то такое слово называется "термин".** А набором букв слово никогда не было, слово это всегда образ чего-то, а не отсылка к другому бессмысленному набору букв. **А номинативное утверждение - это *мем*.** Так вот, ваше **непонимание** идет видимо **по причине** **мемезации** вашей **речи**.

А русские слова при этом часто сами по себе уже являются фразеологизмами.

Русский язык - фразеологический.

Английский - номинативно-предикативный, но беспричинный.

Немецкий - диалектический.

Comment: Интересный ответ! Я вообще очень неравнодушна к теме сравнительного языкознания. Наверное, нельзя хорошо знать и понимать даже свой язык, рассматривая его отдельно от общей языковой среды.

Comment: @Sharon я так полагаю, что если не разрабатывать собственное понимание языка, через логику именно своего языка, естественно в сравнении с другими, то в итоге будем говорить все на рунглише. Звуковой алфавит - это совершенно новое явление. Вот в Корее, которая РК, ввели звукозапись языковую, так там для старшего поколения два разных языка получилось. Это при том, что там первоисточник - это китайские иероглифы. Но в итоге человек лишается речи, а просто ляпает наборы уже заученные или ассоциативные ряды пока внимания хватит, а у поколения тик-тока это секунд 15 составляют.

Comment: А без речи человек не более чем умное животное. Это то, что сейчас делают, создают новый вид "рабочих человекоподобных особей" через языковой и речевой барьер. Я же там спорил недавно с англичанином, это и есть базовая версия языка или стандартный язык - звуковой набор для коммуникации и передачи информации.

Comment: @
Буратино
 Для  меня история английского языка очень интересна, притягивает он меня и отталкивает одновременно. Удивительны суждения  англичан о русской интонации: вроде бы они считают, что их хороша, а мы очень «кричим», грубые такие. А я считаю, что на язык мелодичный, красивый, а у них интонация никакая. И еще не так давно я  с интересом прочитала книгу Стефана Кларка «Англия и Франция: мы любим ненавидеть друг друга». Там  говорится о возникновения английского  языка, о связях его с французским. Но это мнение  писателя, а не языковеда…

Comment: @Sharon Французы, кстати, свой язык очень охраняют, у них все надписи, новости и прочее все только на французском. И говорят все на французском внутри страны, очень не любят английский. Кстати только сейчас заметил, насколько схожа фонетика блажь и плиз, вполне вероятно что родственные слова.

Comment: Да, действительно. А книгу не читали?  Она так интересно написана: язык, история. люди – все там. Как будто видишь, как все было. И про французов я тоже слышала, нам бы с них пример брать, а не орфографию без конца править, да еще на классику замахиваться.

Comment: @Sharon занесу в список литературы которую я не прочитал)

Comment: @Sharon я кажется начинаю догадываться в чем дело: взгляд на язык как на систему знаков, это логическая ошибка в конце концов. Потому что язык проявляется в знаках, знаки - являются языком. НО язык есть не потому что есть система знаков, а потому что есть речь, которая этот язык формирует, что-то до языка. Система знаков это эффект языка, также как сила гравитации не есть падения предметов. Падение предметов - это лишь частное проявление. То есть когда язык замыкают на слово, создается логическая петля, а процесс формирования, рождения языка не получается. Получается язык попугаев.

Comment: @Sharon дело в том, что я тут недавно еще на один вопрос отвечал, на руссишь швайн, рунглишь СЕ) у меня там специфические отношения с комьюнити, но это не так важно. Суть в том что был вопрос: чем отличается речь от выступления, если оба переводятся как speech. Так вот я пришел к выводу, что речь - это не разу не speech(говорение, разговор, диалог), а read  - чтение. В немецком Speech переводят как с одной стороны шпрехен, а с другой стороны реден( rede/reden - от которого и произошло read). Так вот попугаю шпрехают, но не редают, не обладают речью, но могут выгаривать - повторять слова.

Comment: Кроме того есть разница между слухом и зрением (но это уже биология), которая нашла отражение в двух этих понятиях. Одно дело повторять уже знание, а другое дело увидеть это знание - понять, осмыслить, соединить с мыслью, облечь мысль в слова, создав слово-фразу, через образ. Поэтому говорить речь - это повторять по памяти(или вообще читать с листа), читать, а не говорить, вот что получается... А вот когда язык начинают воспринимать на слух, или смотрят сквозь семантику, тогда свой родной язык становится иностранным, нуждающимся в переводе - такой человек лишается речевого разнообразия.

Comment: @Sharon потому что для семантики слово не уникально, а заменимо синонимом. Следовательно и мысль не уникальна(это уже постмодерн начинается) мысль - это отсылка на мысль автора, человек уже не автор мысли, а только повторяет уже кем-то сказанное. И вот тут начинается проблема, человек разучается в речь, сохраняя навыки говорения и повторения услышанных фраз(к месту и не очень) , но он как нейросети учится выражать "мнение" или его подобие.

Comment: Очень интересную тему вы затронули и очень новую для меня, она касается. как я думаю, глубинных процессов в языке. Иногда мне кажется, что я четко вас понимаю, а потом сбиваюсь опять. Хотелось бы сначала осознать сказанное в отдельных деталях, чтобы потом понять в целом, но вот как?  Формат комментариев для этого не подходит, кроме того, хотелось бы узнать мнения других участников.

Comment: А что если я буду задавать  отдельные вопросы по теме, стараясь уложиться в правила сайта? В конце концов мы не только специалисты по запятым, но и немного лингвисты тоже, поэтому общие проблемы языкознания на примере русского языка являются нашей темой. И если вопрос покажется вам интересным, вы могли бы уделить ему немного внимания?

Comment: @Sharon уделить могу, но я вряд ли хоть сколько-то специалист по языку, а мои вопросы и ответы не от "знания", а скорее от незнания и непонимания многих моментов, особенно тех, которые кажутся мне не логичными. И мне конечно интересно пообщаться на эти темы в любом формате, потому что мои ответы это скорее рассуждение для себя, а не совсем те ответы которые, вероятно, ожидают получить спрашивающие.

Comment: Я так не думаю. Иногда не специалисты по языку (без официальных дипломов) мыслят интереснее, чем специалисты, связанные системой и обученные по системе. Здесь разные варианты могут быть. Я все-таки попробую...  Сформулирую один из частных вопросов так, чтобы было интересно. Но вот пропустят ли, не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

Любое слово живого языка со временем может приобрести новые дополнительные значения. Если прежние значения слова «забылись», то это выглядит как изменение значения слова.
Возможна ситуация, когда слово приобретает два противоположных значения и оба этих значения мирно сосуществуют в современном (нам) языке.
Такую ситуацию называют термином энантиосемия.
Энантиосемия - противопоставление двух лексических единиц (слов, морфем, устойчивых словосочетаний), восходящих к одной общей лексеме.
https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F

Существует межъязыковая энантиосемия. Например: польское uroda означает «красота», woń — «запах, аромат», zapominać — «забывать»; в переводе с чешского čerstvý значит «свежий», potraviny — «продукты», ovoce — «фрукты», úžasný — «восхитительный»; сербское «вредност» переводится как «ценность».
Источник: Ситуация, когда одно слово имеет противоположные значения, называется энантиосемия — Фактрум

Примеры энантиосемии в русском языке:

- бесценный — «не имеющий никакой цены» и «значимость предмета выше любой предлагаемой цены»;
- одалживать — «брать» в дол» и «давать» в долг,
- занимать – «давать» взаймы и «получать» займ(ы),
- завязывать — может означать и «начинать» (завязывать) отношения и «заканчивать» (завязывать) с вредной привычкой;
- прослушать — «выслушать и воспринять» и «отвлечься, пропустить мимо ушей».

Сдвиг значения слова в сторону абсолютной противоположности — это вполне закономерное для языка явление.
https://moluch.ru/conf/phil/archive/233/11558/
Явление энантиосемии - семантический процесс, фиксирующий изменения и движение понятий в языке и меняющего значение слов в результате их функционирования в различных условиях.
Энантиосемия представляет собой одновременное сосуществование двух противоположных значений в пределах семантики одного и того же слова.  Энантиосемия — это источник развития языка, один из аспектов видения человеком объективной реальности, не противоречащий принципам строения языка.
Романчук, Ю. В. Что такое энантиосемия? / Ю. В. Романчук.
// Молодой ученый. — 2016. — № 1 (105). — С. 904-907.
https://moluch.ru/archive/105/24550/

Comment: Овощ - плод, вонь - благовонье, просто резкий запах, запамятовать - забывать, урода - уродился, а не уродина, почему черствый это мягкий - ну такой себе вопрос, хотелось бы узнать как это чехи объясняют. Вообще не всё слова поддаются оценке моральной значимости: бесценный - слово выходящее за критерии значимости, а вот обесцененный - утративший цену, дешевый.  Ну с долгом и займом путаница мб, завязывать - начинать, ну такое себе, прослушать - от того и прослушать, что это никак не связано с тем сколько кто-то воспринял, услышал, а говорит только о том, что кто-то сидел там, и мог слушать.

Comment: Вообще в русском языке слов с четким положительным или отрицательным значением не так много, потому что язык не про полярные стороны и почти любое слово может иметь форму вплоть до противоположных значений. Причем негативное значение может быть как при недостатке , так и при избытке какого-то качества. Ну и красавица - может значить "ну ты и уродина". А в польском уродство содержит корни увечий - порезанный, глухой, слепой. То есть там слова нет урод - тот кто не уродился, там есть увечный.

Comment: Существует версия, что «черствый» - значит «отрезанный». Если отрезано только что, то чехи правы. Но если отрезано давно, то мы правее.

Comment: Черствый всё же от черта, а не совсем от отрезать), черствый человек - негибкий, имеющий определенные предубеждения, слишком явные черты и не склонный к чувственному восприятию, следовательно и к изменению суждений, костный. Интересно было бы узнать, применяется ли черствый к человеческому характеру в Чехии - чёрствый человек, это человек с мягким характером?(я думаю нет, не применяется) Черствый в чешском - это свежий в смысле "новый", неюзанный, то есть скорее граница между новый и не новым, только что отрезанный/отнятый, да, только не "отрезанный", а "только что".