# Почему «мысль изреченная есть ложь»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика

Всем известен этот **афоризм**, взятый из стихотворения Ф. Тютчева:

*Как сердцу высказать себя?*

*Другому как понять тебя?*

*Поймет ли он, чем ты живешь?*

***Мысль изреченная есть ложь…***

Но так ли это? Ведь есть и противоположное мнение: «***Кто ясно мыслит, тот ясно излагает***».

Тем не менее мы с одинаковой готовностью повторяем обе эти фразы, в то время как надо бы уж определиться.

И это не только философия, как можно подумать, но и **проблемы языкознания.** Вот эта сторона вопроса для меня особенно интересна. **Насколько точен наш язык,** думаем ли мы об этом, когда подбираем языковую форму для какого-либо содержания? Какие проблемы возможны при поиске нужного слова?

**Примечание.** Не так давно эти вопросы были обозначены в темах [Сами себе или самим себе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474235/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5)
[О словах со старославянским корнем](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474262/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC)

А как думаете вы?  Спасибо.

**P.S.** От себя могу добавить, что мне очень помогают **слова-образы**. К примеру, недавно мне встретилось авторское определение "язык попугаев", и сразу стало понятнее, о чем идет речь. Это как якорь для нашего сознания.

**Приложение** (цитаты по теме)

*Когда у мыслителей быстро вертятся мысли, у немыслящей публики кружится голова*. (Ключевский Василий Осипович (1841 — 1911) — русский историк.)

— *Я — читала, — не сразу отозвалась девушка. — Но, видите ли: слишком обнаженные слова не доходят до моей души. Помните у Тютчева: «Мысль изреченная есть ложь». Для меня Метерлинк более философ, чем этот грубый и злой немец.*.. (Горький Максим, Жизнь Клима Самгина, 1936.)

***Всем большое спасибо за ответы и за внимание к вопросу!! Интересная получилась дискуссия.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для меня "мысль изреченная есть ложь" - это вариант фразы иной философии, но уже восточной - "Дао выраженное словами не есть истинное Дао". Хотя, возможно, Тютчев мог самостоятельно прийти к ней. Вообще практика молчания может быть связана в том числе и с религиозными практиками, когда монахи давали молчание и соблюдали его, чтобы не создавать лишние предпосылки для возникновения греховных деяний, но наблюдали за миром, созерцали. Говорящий не знает, а знающий не говорит/доказывающий не знает, а знающий не доказывает - тоже из "Дао Де Дзин".

Насчет противоречивости, в рамках формальной(линейной) логики да, противоречивая фраза, как и почти вся китайская книга, но формальной логикой логика не заканчивается. С точки зрения той же диалектики это начинает приобретать смысл.

Мышление в свою очередь связано с речью напрямую, потому что в традиционной советской(а может и русской) философии и психологии есть понятие "мысленная речь" - то есть речь без использования слов. Мысленная речь - это те самые внутренние монологи, которыми изобилует русская литература (Достоевский, Толстой и тд.). И граница проходит где-то по немцам. Фрейд, Ницше, Гуссерль, Хайдеггер также во многом писали про "мысленную речь", хотя использовали для этого другие выражения. То есть про мышление до языка. Язык попугаев - это как раз из статьи про немецкие redan и sprechen, [английской статьи)](https://angelikasgerman.co.uk/what-is-the-difference-between-reden-sprechen-sagen/), то есть для них нужно указать фактически, где не так, и они нашли - у немецких попугаев не так(там в самом конце). А redan(есть правда вопросы почему redan, а не reden) в свою очередь это основа для английского [read](https://www.etymonline.com/word/read#etymonline_v_7319:%7E:text=Proto%2DGermanic%20*redan). В то время как "читать" по-немецки listen - слушать/прослушать.

Но проблем тут множество. Потому что есть путаница с рядом ключевых понятий:

Во-первых, "изреченная" Тютчев употребляет как сказанная, проговорённая, произнесенная вслух.

Во-вторых, слово ложь. Почему ложь? Однако, если посмотреть на фразу из "Дао Де Цзин", то ложь - это то, что "не есть". Дело в том, что у немцев есть слово "есть" -ist, а у англичан - нет(насчет французов не знаю). to be - это не то, что есть, а то, что является чем-то другим, соответствует чему-то по ряду ключевых признаков.  Если соответствует, верифицируется - то это является и true(верно), а если нет - то это не является этим и lie(ложь). Это основа формальной логики. Но у англичан помимо этого, нет еще одного слова - истина, откровения, которое греческое алетейя. Об этом писал Хайдеггер, когда обнаружил, отсутствие такого понятия в принципе на западе, потому что оно нарушает всю логичность формальной логики. Как что-то может быть только всегда верно? - это не логично. Сама по себе верификация правды(а не истины) -  это чисто латинская процедура, которая в последующем становится основой для *договора*...

Хотя, даже в английском есть слова которые вываливаются из контекста явлений, и их как раз принято с заглавной буквы. То есть Cat - это имя кота, истинный кот, а cat - котом являющийся, имеющий кошачью признаки, обозначающие кота, называние животного котом, номинатив. В то время как по-русски *кот* - это скорее *Кот* по-английски, потому что по-русски *мой кот*/*кот который мне нравится*/*кот, которого я вижу, что он есть* самый кошачий из котов, а все остальные коты - это подобие именно того кота, который мне нравится. Совершенно иная логика вырисовывается... Если смотрели сериал "Ходячие мертвецы", то там в роли демиурга часто выступает Дэрил, так вот, он своей собаке дал имя Dog - Пёс. И это чуть ли не единственная собака в сериале, то есть он "сотворил" собаку из ничего), но истинную собаку, настоящую, самую реальную.

Поэтому и получается, что "мысль сказанная (облеченная в слова-номинативы, стандартный язык) есть ложь", то есть не "есть истина". И показательно, что Тютчев использует для название именно латинское слово, обозначающие молчание.

Однако, ошибка применять эту фразу везде и всюду, потому что у всего есть область воздействия, нет бесконечных понятий. Образ, что такое образ? Образ, это не часть чего-то, не совсем. Раз - это от разрезать, то есть раз - это не кусок торта, правый или левый, а это именно линия разреза. Раз - это одно отделенное или выделенное из общего целого. Об - это круг, образ - это граница отделения объекта, понятия, сущности, а не сам объект, понятие сущность.  Так вот, чтобы понять что-то, нужно ограничить зону его влияния, обособить в границах, образовать, тогда можно говорить что это что-то есть само по себе. Наиболее близкое к образу, как мне кажется, понятие - это *ноэма* Гуссерля, которая в свою очередь является не образом, но следствием образного действия/образного опыта.

Поэтому я бы избегал мемичного и бездумного повторения любой звучащей фразы, даже такой казалось бы универсальной, как у Тютчева. Но как образ или способ мышления она вполне имеет место быть. А в идеале, нужно мысленный образ заключенный во фразе каждый раз облекать(или обрекать) в новые слова-номинативы(и не забывать о предикативных связка), в соотнесении с текущей ситуацией, это обуславливает изменение языка. Но последнее не говорит о том, что номинативы и предикаты и прочая формализация речи есть сама речь. Нет, основа речи - это то, что не формализуется, то есть границы слов и значений, образы. Понятие образа, принципиально определяет наш русский язык(кстати англичане пишут Russian и любой другой язык с большой буквы - именование, а не номинатив), в русской речи большинство слов есть образы, а не термины, term - "limit in time, set or appointed period", то есть слова постулирующие временные изменения, не являющиеся чем-то постоянным, ограниченный по времени воздействия. Русские образы ограничены, но они вне времени или модальности, они уникальны, а не являются чем-то еще.

Comment: Классный ответ! Просто энциклопедия знаний по сравнительному языкознанию. И еще  – умение сравнивать и анализировать. Нестандартное мышление – вот что ценно! Другими словам, читать и не начитаться.

Comment: @Sharon ну это кратко то, с чем я столкнулся и о чем думаю последние несколько месяцев. Пытаюсь увязать в нейкий нарратив, рассказ, который можно скорее читать и видеть, а не повторять и слышать, да.

Comment: Мне было очень интересно "читать и видеть". Спасибо вам! Интересно, скажут ли что о вашем ответе другие наши участники.

Answer (score 5):

Прямую связь между мыслями и речью можно ощутить лишь в математической формуле. А языковое фиксирование мысли часто приводит к разногласиям в трактовке изложенного, к противоречивым рассуждениям и оценкам и ложному представлению о предмете авторского осмысления. Что говорить о словах отдельного автора, когда коллективное творчество, отражённое в серьёзных текстах, требует часто великого усилия для синхронизации их восприятия и смысла.

Этот монументальный перл — *Мысль изреченная есть ложь*— не подвинуть ни искренностью пишущего, ни опытом читающего, хотя начитанность позволяет «судить» о внятности и достоинстве сказанного. Чтецы и актёры своим прочтением и озвучением только ширят рамку кругозора: множат версии *лжи*.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. А вы можете привести примеры слов или суждений. где форма  не соответствует содержанию, то есть является ложной.

Comment: И еще такой вопрос. Мы все не любим словесные штампы, но даже самое оригинальное своё суждение мы вынуждены заключать в готовые словесные формы. Не на этом ли этапе мысль становится ложью в той или иной степени? Все дело в том, насколько удачно или неудачно мы делаем свой выбор.

Comment: Вот видите, как всё запущено... Скажу ещё короче: мысль, закодированная в слова, впоследствии расшифрованная, становится иной, изменённой, какие бы усилия не прилагались сторонами. Стороны не лгут (сказка — ложь, да в ней... не ложь), формы не ложны и соответствуют содержанию и т. д., но инструмент мысль всегда преломляет. Надо спросить у поэтов, они не согласятся, наверное.

Comment: Да, поэтов было бы интересно послушать, ведь они говорят нами на языке художественных образов. Неплохо было бы использовать их опыт и в нашей речевой практике, этот момент всегда был привлекателен для меня.

Answer (score 1):

**мысль изреченная есть ложь** это противоречивая фраза, так как сама опровергает себя.

Что же имел в виду поэт, попробуем разобраться:

```
Молчи, скрывайся и таи
И чувства и мечты свои -
Пускай в душевной глубине
Встают и заходят оне
Безмолвно, как звезды в ночи,-
Любуйся ими - и молчи.
Как сердцу высказать себя?
Другому как понять тебя?
Поймёт ли он, чем ты живёшь?
```

Имеется в виду, что словами невозможно выразить чувства другому человеку, если он сам это не испытывал. Так что фраза как таковая неудачная, но для стиха сойдет. Для примера можно привести ветеранов, которые не любят говорить о победных боях. Почему они не любят, спросите их. Они вам наговорят кучу правильных мыслей, но все будет ложь для вас, пока сам там не побываешь.

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий** к ответу user190920

Спасибо за ваше мнение (голос от меня), но мне **не совсем ясно**, почему фраза Тютчева опровергает себя и в чем ее противоречие, вот это было бы интересно послушать.

Стихотворение Тютчева имеет **определенную историю**. «Оно появилось в 1830 году и  называется «Silentium!», что в переводе означает «Молчание!» или «Молчи!». Произведение часто переписывалось из-за того, что для Тютчева оно было особенно важным. Свадьба с Элеонорой Петерсон послужила вдохновением для написания этого произведения. Поэт был без ума влюблён в прекрасную немку и в момент их отношений был поистине счастлив».  https://dzen.ru/a/XLD4nfIfYgCzzt3x

Что было дальше, тоже известно, совсем не безоблачны были эти отношения.
https://dzen.ru/a/YGwa8QWqKWnJWIua

Но это история поэта, **а у стиха своя история**. Образно говоря, пишется она **богами, а не людьми**.  Фраза стала известным афоризмом, и нам уже на **так важно**, что имел в виду поэт. Он говорил о чувствах, но читается в нем **нечто большее.**

Особенно это становится ясно, если сравнить стихотворение **с другим «Silentium!»**, и это уже О. Мандельштам, 1910 год.  «В третьей части стихотворения лирический герой выражает желание вернуться к основам жизни и обрести ту «кристаллическую ноту» и чистоту, что дана ему и всему живому от рождения». https://litrekon.ru/analiz-proizvedenij/silentium-mandelshtam/

А это лирическое стихотворение Тютчева **"пошло по рукам**")) Теперь уже им заинтересовались любители "логических парадоксов".  Это законченная (изреченная) мысль? Но тогда она ложная, отрицает сама себя! https://dzen.ru/a/X1BqKyUG8hHRFs2J

Вот как тут **предохранять** свой внутренний мир от внешнего? Только если лирический дневник подальше убрать...)) Или писать, как Мандельштам, – понимают сказанное им очень немногие, но ведь **какое красивое!**

Она еще не родилась,

Она и музыка и слово,

И потому всего живого

Ненарушаемая связь...

Но вернемся в наше время. Афоризм Тютчева понимается по-разному, а это свидетельствует о значимости сказанного и о глубине истинно художественного мышления http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2521762-pravda-li-chto-mysl-izrechennaja-est-lozh.html

Comment: Я тоже думал, что у фразы есть больший смысл, чем тот, что указан в стихе. Но нет, он не просматривается. А все объяснения в интернете - надуманная чушь, не спроста же вы задали этот вопрос, там такие объяснения, что в трех соснах черт ногу сломит, нормальному человеку не понять. При том, что должно быть наоборот. Смысл афоризмов должен просматриваться многими людьми в бытовых ситуациях, только тогда они будут афоризмами. Здесь такой смысл - один.

Comment: Да, мнений много, но я не стала всё называть "чушью", к тому  же определенную информацию можно извлечь  из любого высказывания. Коме того, в любом мнении есть какая-то доля истины и какая-то доля лжи, все дело только в пропорции))

Comment: И почему только в быту нужны афоризмы? Взять того же Мандельштама, который продолжает тему Тютчева, но при этом высказывает уже чисто философское понимание предмета.

Comment: По определению, афоризм  - это то что пошло и закрепилось в народе, подпитываясь постоянными встречами в бытовых (обычных, жизненных, частых) ситуациях. То есть надо не просто объяснить фразу заумными трактатами, а предъявить простые ситуация, в которых для простого человека это будет ясно, иначе это не афоризм.

Comment: Я видела определение https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Афоризм  "АФОРИЗМ (от др.-греч. ἀφορισμός краткое изречение[1]) — оригинальная законченная мысль, изречённая и записанная в лаконичной запоминающейся форме и впоследствии неоднократно воспроизводимая другими людьми.  

В афоризме достигается предельная концентрация непосредственного сообщения и того контекста, в котором мысль воспринимается окружающими слушателями или читателем". Здесь вроде бы не подчеркивался, что в быту и для простых читателей. Да из практики видно, что сфера применения афоризмов очень разнообразная.

Comment: Да, там говорится о группе людей, но насколько она широка не говорится. Это могут быть и два человека, объединенные какой-то специфической предметной областью. Но у нашего афоризма уже есть некий бытовой смысл, закрепившийся за ним в быту ( в широкой группе). Мальденштамп в своей статье говорит ровно о том же смысле: "Так же, как и Тютчев в практически одноименном стихотворении «Silentium!», Мандельштам говорит о том, что некоторые вещи можно познать лишь в их первоначальном виде.". Такие вещи как секс, наркотики, рок-н-рол.

Comment: Из практики видно, что все афоризмы понятны простому обывателю и он может использовать их поучая своих внуков.

Comment: Смелые у вас выводы)) Вы, наверное, стихи уж точно не пишете, нет у вас сомнений ни в чем. А вот Мандельштам постоянно сомневался, во всем видел поэтическое, необыкновенное. Например, стихотворение «Только детские книги читать» было написано в 1908 г. когда ему всего 17 лет, а стих считается мировым шедевром.  Вот что говорят про него наши современники: «Я могла ощутить неосязаемую связь с человеком, который жил в прошлом веке. Наверное, в этом и есть феномен гениальности: чувствовать другого через огромное пространство времени». https://dzen.ru/a/XzTjEOeLaS4dWRi2